# Find all natural solutions for $\binom mn=1984$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, diophantine-equations

> Find all positive integers $m$ and $n$ such that $${m \choose n}= 1984$$

My approach:

It is easy to define $m=1984$ and $n=1$ or $1983$. But how to show that there are no other solutions or, if any, then how to find them?

Comment: If it were me, I'd notice that ${m\choose 2}=\frac{m(m-1)}2$ is going to be bigger than $1984$ for any terribly large $m$ (and I could do the same with ${m\choose 3}$ and so on), but this still seems to require a lot of work. I'd be interested in seeing a more slick solution. Maybe there's a solution involving factorization? $1984=2^6\times 31$, which seems like not very many prime factors to be a binomial... (Note especially that if ${m\choose n}=1984$ then $1984n!$ is the product of $n$ consecutive integers, which at least eliminates $n=2$ easily)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that $31\mid 1984$, hence we need $m\ge 31$. Then if $3\le n\le m-3$, we have ${m\choose n}\ge {m\choose 3}=\frac{m(m-1)(m-2)}{6}\ge {31\choose 3}=4495$. Remains the case $n=2$ (or $n=m-2)$ and $1984=\frac{m(m-1)}{2}$. Since this expression in $m$ is increasing and ${63\choose 2}=1953<1984<2016={64\choose 2}$, no solution with $n=2$ (or $n=m-2$) exists. We conclude that the two solutions you found are all there is.